# Renaming Namespace for a Managed Beta package

Tags: namespace

I have a Managed Beta Package in Dev. Org. with a Namespace.  How can I rename the Namespace in the same org.  I'm trying to avoid opening a new Dev. Org and migrating components and code to the new Org.

Comment: You can't. It even tells you when creating it that it cannot be changed. Only hope would be to see if SF support has some magic they could offer

Comment: Would an alternative be to create a new package in the same org with a different namespace.  Then Add the components to the new package?  Can I have two Managed packages in the sames org?

Comment: An org currently can only have one namespace so that would not be possible

Comment: So it appears that I have to create the new Dev. Org and migrate the components over.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To work with multiple namespace, it is a good idea to have two separate folders, one without namespace (unmanaged code) and another with namespace (managed packaged code) and create script to prepend namespace where it is appropriate (wipe out packaged folder, copy unpackaged folder to packaged and prepend namespaces where needed).

In such case, change of namespace is a simple configuration change in `sfdx-project.json` file for 2GMP and rerunning the script to prepend namespaces.

However, for 1GMP you still have to create a separate Dev Edition org and migrate code there manually.